# Can't use `gem-install` command in pry

Tags: ruby, pry

I tried to install a gem by using `gem-install` command in pry, but it failed.

```
% pry
pry(main) > gem-install pry-doc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/rubygem.rb:60:in `install'
```

I could install the gem by using `gem` command from bash.
Is there something I must configure to use `gem-install` command in `pry`?

Comment: Thanks, that was a fun short code dive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't used PRY for a while.

Looking through the source code found the gem-install command code.

Look at your `Gem.configuration['gem']` and you will find that it is nil.

It looks like this comes from your `~/.gemrc` settings or default values.

In your ~/.gemrc file, if you place the line `gem: ''`

This solved the issue for me as it is no longer doing the split on nil, but on the assigned value for `gem:` key in the `.gemrc` file.

Comment: Thanks! and I confirmed this bug is already fixed in github latest revision.

Comment: Not published on the rubygems site as of this date though, I guess.

Comment: Huge thanks! I found this happens with the latest Pry with OSX, it's been driving me crazy for some time now.